# visual studio 2015 comm is automatically closing

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed "Visual studio 2015 Community" on my "Dell Inspiron  N4050, core I5, 4GB RAM, 64bits windows 7 ultimate"

When the installation finished I rebooted and opened Visual studio 2015 Community.

It opens only for 4 seconds, then the window disappears!! (loses-Automatically) this is the first time I see such problem, usually there is bug window / report, but now I am really confused and I don't know how to solve the problem!